# RPI UART receiving weird data

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, serial-port, pyserial, uart

I have a Raspberry Pi 3B+ with an IC card reader that uses UART. The program is written in Python.
The data it receives is often wrong, but sometimes accurate.

There are 3 variations of the same card:

```py
b'\\x02\\t\\x01\\xf4\\xec7\\xf6\\xd1\\x03'
HEX: f4ec37f6
DEC: 4109121526

b'\\x01\\x02\\x9d\\x85\\\\xfe'
HEX: 855cfe
DEC: 0008740094

b'\\x01\\x86\\x9d\\xc5\\\\xfe'
HEX: c55cfe
DEC: 0012934398
```

The first variation is the right one, which the card reader of my computer always reads the same result 4109121526, and it seldom appears on the RPI. For the other 2 variations, they always show up without a specific pattern.

The baud rate is 9600, I tried other rates, but it got even worse. The timeout is 0.5s, doesn't seem to matter.
Tried switching to a better power supply, nothing changed.
The store that sold me the reader told me to check the protocol and do data validation, but I have no idea what he's talking about. Is that related to the issue?

Got any idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please do [tour] and read about [mcve] then click [edit] and add your code along with details of the reader you are using.

Comment: Back slash is 0x5c. I do not see the problem in your dump. Can you clarify? (At least what I see from the first example, that you are trying to print the 4 bytes after 3 bytes from the start and that is **correct** dump of the last two dumps)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The card reader returns 3 values randomly, but I only want the first result, and I have no idea why the second and third result appear. 
After further testing, the device actually works fine and only show the first result in my home, but once I bring the device back to my office, the other two results come back. 
I’m using the same power supply, also I made sure all wires are well connected. I have no idea why switching venues will affect the card reader at all :(